# SQL query and display only date

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `celula` (
  `ID_Celula` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `integrantes` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Celula`)
);

INSERT INTO `celula` (`ID_Celula`, `integrantes`) VALUES
(1, '2:2014-08-13,4:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13,7:2014-08-13'),
(2, '3:2014-08-13,5:2014-08-13,6:2014-08-13');
```

How do I show only the date of the column members?

online test http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1729fd/4

Comment: Maybe you should normalise the data.

Comment: I do not understand, how so?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: The problem is that this table is old, and customers have many records in it. I'm trying to think of something, without the need to dismantle the table. Searching this code requires, but not all http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1729fd/4 dates

Comment: What is the required expected output?

Comment: The idea is to get all the dates, grouped by month. I want to mount a graph. I want to know how many records have each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```sql
SELECT YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month, COUNT(*) count
  FROM
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ':', 1) id, 
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ':', -1) AS DATE) date
    FROM
  (
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(integrantes, ',', n), ',', -1) value
      FROM celula CROSS JOIN 
    (
      SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
      FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
     ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ) tally
     WHERE n <= 1 + (LENGTH(integrantes) - LENGTH(REPLACE(integrantes, ',', '')))
  ) q
) o
 GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Output:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | COUNT |
|------|-------|-------|
| 2014 |     8 |     7 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1729fd/16)** demo

*If you need to split more than 100 values you can easily tweak the inner most `SELECT` to produce more rows, or you can even simplify things you make it a persistent (tally) table in your database.*

Comment: Friend, it worked, thanks! Our many selects, I would never get to do this kkkkk. Another question, with so many selects could not know where to put a condition to display only the YEAR and MONTH desire.

Comment: I did, I was doing wrong. The correct was **WHERE YEAR(date) = '2014' && MONTH(date) = '07'**

Comment: How do I display only the amount I play it GET? example **file.php?ID_Celula=2**

Comment: @Tiago What is the problem with the answer to your original question? Is there any particular reason you unaccepted it?

Comment: Good day friend. this is a continuation of the same subject. I just forgot that little detail, was now only repair. I need to inform the ID_Celula which desire grab the data. Could you help me in this little detail? example **file.php?ID_Celula=2**